# Listen on 3rd Party App-Start

Tags: android

Is it possible to implement something like this to my app:

- User starts App2,
- App1 noticed that,
- App1 starts a service
- User is all the time in App2
- User closes/stops App2
- App1 stops the Service

If this is possible or just a part is possible post an answer, I would appreciate it!!

Comment: Sounds stupid, why would you need that?

Comment: I need it so my two apps can communicate with each other

Comment: Use a `ContentProvider` to access data from one app in another.